# Finding specific relation in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following problem. I created a table named parentchildrenName. This Table includes the name of a parent and the name  of one child in every row. Now i want to return the names of a pairs of parents which have the same child with their childName. This means it should return the name of parent1 and parent2 with the specific childName like this:

```
  SELECT parentName1, parentName2 childName FROM parentchildren
```

I am not quit sure how i could make this command work in mysql any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: That duplication contains answers with query methods which will work from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 8 to query child parent relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self join on equal child names but different parent names.

```
SELECT p.parentname,
       p.childname,
       m.parentname
       FROM parentchildren p
            INNER JOIN parentchildren m
                       ON m.childname = p.childname
                          AND m.parentname < p.parentname;
```

If you want each parent pair twice, with the parents switching positions you can change `<` to `<>`. Or change it to `>` if you want to have each pair only one but switch the positions in all of the pairs.